# Interaction of module defer with DOMContentLoaded for inline scripts in browser

Tags: javascript, async-await, module, domcontentloaded, top-level-await

Here is what I understand based upon MDN [Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer):

- All JavaScript modules defer automatically.
- Deferring a module prevents the `DOMContentLoaded` event from firing until the module finishes.
- Using an inline `<script type="module">` makes the script a module and defers it automatically.

Thus I would expect `DOMContentLoaded` not to be called until a `<script type="module">` is finished. But I tried this code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
…
<script type="module">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded fired");
  });

  const fooBar = await fetch("foo.bar");
  console.log("finished loading data");

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("starting to process data");
    //try to process fooBar
  });
}
…
```

Here I would expect the entire script to run, awaiting for the fetching of "foo.bar" and assigning `fooBar` before `DOMContentLoaded` is fired. Yet in the console I see:

> `DOMContentLoaded fired`
>
> `finished loading data`

I never see "starting to process data". It seems that `DOMContentLoaded` is being fired before the module finishes.

There must be part of the documentation I misinterpreted. How is `DOMContentLoaded` being called before the completion of a module?

Comment: I'd think it only waits for the module to be executed, it doesn't mean it waits for it to finish when you use top-level `await`.

Comment: But the MDN reference for `defer` I provided says, "Scripts with the `defer` attribute will prevent the `DOMContentLoaded` event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating."

Comment: Yes, but that was probably written before the introduction of top-level `await`.